# Code works perfectly in iPython, but gives error message when run in terminal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run this code in `iPython`, it works perfectly. But when I run the same script from my terminal, I get an error message: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unstack'`

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

stocks = {'xom': '2015-01-01', 'aapl': '2014-01-01', 'dvn': '2013-01-01'}

def fetch_data_from_yahoo(d_stocks):
    df_list = []
    for symbol, start_date in d_stocks.items():
        df_list.append(web.get_data_yahoo(symbol, start_date)['Adj Close'])
    return pd.concat(df_list, keys=list(d_stocks.keys()))

fetch_data_from_yahoo(stocks)

fetch_data_from_yahoo(stocks).unstack(0)
```

Comment: @ZdaR thank you for the edit

Comment: Does python `pandas.concat` return `None`?

Comment: works for me in both cases

Comment: Your example is working for me (both in ipython and in terminal). Is it possible that you are behind a proxy and there are different settings in your interactive environment and your terminal? That would explain the `None` returned by your function.

Comment: @chris-sc I honestly don't know. I will look into it though, that would make sense.